# Phoenix 1.2 Won't Upgrade to 1.3?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have Phoenix 1.2.4 currently running on OSX.  I'm trying to upgrade to 1.3 using:

```
$ mix archive.install https://github.com/phoenixframework/archives/raw/master/phx_new.ez
```

It doesn't give me an error, but doesn't upgrade either.  What am I missing?

Here's the Terminal output:

> Mb:~ t9$ elixir -v 
>   rlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.1] [source] [64-bit]
>   [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
>
> Elixir 1.5.2
>
> Mb:~ t9$ mix archive.install https://github.com/phoenixframework/ar
>   chives/raw/master/phx_new.ez
>
> Found existing entry: /Users/t9/.mix/archives/phx_new
>
> Are you sure you want to replace it with
>
> "https://github.com/phoenixframework/archives/raw/master/phx_new.ez"?
>   [Yn] y
>
> - creating .mix/archives/phx_new
>
> Mb:~ t9$ mix phoenix.new --version
>
> Phoenix v1.2.4

Comment: You mean 1.3 and not 1.4 right? 1.3 is the latest release right now.

Comment: Yes, my mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new (version >= 1.3.0) generator is named `phx.new`; `phoenix.new` is the old one. `mix phx.new --version` should give you 1.3.0 as output, which is the latest release version as of today.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have Phoenix 1.3 installed, if you use the generator `phoenix.new` the project will be initialized with a 1.2 structure, meaning you will have your web directory alone instead of being inside the `lib` directory with the `myapp_web`, to create a new project with the new structure you need to use the `mix phx.new`.